# How can I programmatically update jquery.mmenu.js options?

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu

I'm testing mmenu.js (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl) as an option for a mobile site drawer menu, and it works great, but the one issue I'm having is trying to update the option values *after* the menu has been created. Specifically, I would like to have the "dragOpen" option set to "true" by default, but want to disable it when the touch event is triggered on elements that have horizontal scrolling.

I have another plugin handling horizontal touch swiping of a slideshow-style element so I'm trying to take advantage of hammer.js, which is already being used by mmenu.js for the dragOpen event, and change "dragOpen" to "false" when the touched target is that slideshow container:

```
$(function() {
    var navMenuLeft = $('nav#menu-left').mmenu({
        position: 'left',
        searchfield: true,
        dragOpen: true,
        threshold: 150
    });

    $('.swiper-container').hammer().on('touch', function(event){
        // this triggers properly, but I seem unable to access the options for
        // the mmenu object. If I log "navMenuLeft" it returns the #menu-left
        // element rather than the mmenu object, so "navMenuLeft.opts" is undefined
        console.log('touched swiper');
    });
});
```

I tried increasing the threshold to a number greater than what is required to swipe the slides, but a minimal swipe on the slideshow is still triggering the dragOpen. I've searched the documentation pretty thoroughly and feel like I'm just missing something simple. Or maybe rather than changing the dragOpen option, there's a way to set elements to exclude from dragging to open the menu?

I have considered that the dragOpen is not critical to the user experience, and as a last resort will just disable it completely, but I'm hoping to find a solution because there may be other cases where updating different options programmatically is also necessary.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the most logic approach would be to stop the drag event(s) from bubbling up the DOM.
For example, if you have this markup:

```
<div id="page">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <div id="carousel"></div>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Try stopping the event from bubbling up beyond the #carousel div:

```
$("#carousel").on( "drag", function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    event.gesture.stopPropagation();
});
```

This way, if a user drags across the #carousel div, the drag event won't bubble up to the #page div.

p.s. Programmatically updating the options for the plugin is not possible at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, but if anyone else is looking for an answer and stumbles across this like I did,

```
var options = {dragLockToAxis: true};
                var hammertime = new Hammer($("#Draging_element"), options);
                hammertime.on("dragleft dragright drag swipeleft swiperight touchstart",        function(ev) {
   ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

the main part you are looking at is the hammertime.on() with all the events.  the reason for all the events is that jquery.mmenu uses several events to trigger the drag functionally and you need to call stopPropagation on all of them.

Works like a charm :-) 
enjoy

Comment: It should be `ev.srcEvent.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Also this prevents the horizontal scroll on child element and you want exactly the opposite... isn't it?